# Twitter API retweet button implementation (manipulate original tweet)

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth

I'm currently working on a website which is displaying users tweets from the twitter API.

I want to implement a "retweet" button on my site, which retweets the original tweet and adds a "via @myTwitterAccount".

How can I do that? I searched for twitter intents, but with this method I can't add strings to the tweet.

Coding has been done so far with PHP/MySQL and some jQuery for comfort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using @anywhere, which is perfect if you don't want to hassle with oauth.

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/anywhere/welcome